# How to get File both MD5 and SHA1 checksum at the same time when upload a new file?

Tags: java, file, md5, sha1

I am working on a storage system. Users upload files to the server.

On the server side, I want to implement a program to get the checksums of the file using both MD5 and SHA1.

I know how to calculate checksums using DigestInputStream functions, but it seems only supports one method (either MD5 or SHA1) a time. 
How can I calculate both MD5 and SHA1 a the same time when dealing with the upload stream in JAVA?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

Use two `MessageDigest` instances (one for MD5 and one for SHA1) and feed the bytes you read into both.

Comment: You need two DigestInputStream instances with one nested in the other.

Comment: @LeeMeador Your solution would also work but is probably less efficient because of the nested streams.

Comment: +1 @LeeMeador.  The nested streams are likely to have minimal or nonexistent overhead.

Comment: @Henry You are probably right but the classes implementing the Stream interface are typically quite efficient. It just might be good enough.

Comment: you can tee off an OutputStream from your InputStream using a [TeeInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html)

Comment: @LeeMeador I agree, just checked the source, the overhead is pretty low.

Answer (score 1):

as java-ish pseudocode, since you can look up the API for OpenSSL or BSafe or the Java Crypto API on your own...

```
Buffered reader = ...;
char[MY_ARRAY_SIZE] buf = ...;

while( true ) {
  int count = reader.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
  if( count == -1 ) { break };

  /* You'll need to check for the right API and handle errors yourself */
  md5.add(buf, count);
  sha256.add(buf, count);
}

String md5sum = base64(md5.finalize()); // assumes an appropriate base64 method
String sha256sum = base64(sha256.finalize());
```